# ajax refresh - how to remove the blinking

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an MVC application that has an Admin page that I need to update the data displaying every 10 seconds (in case the data has changed in the database). I am using ajax but I am getting a blinking with the reload. What is the best way to achieve this without the obvious blink? NOTE: I am new at ajax.

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<RangeTimer.Models.UserName>


<div class="container"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">


    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add Name to list for range time", "AddUserName", new { target = "_blank" })
       <br />
     </div>
     <hr />
    <div id="Update">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
            </th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td id="FullName">

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
                </td>

                @Html.HiddenFor((modelItem => item.Id))
                <td>

                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFromAdmin", new { id = item.Id })

                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
</div>


<script>


   function refresh(){
       $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("Admin", "UserNames")',
           type: "post",
           cache: false,
           success: function(data){
                 $("#Update").html(data);

           }
       });
   }

$(document).ready(function(){
    refresh(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is Ready
});

//Refresh after 10000 milliseconds
setInterval(refresh, 10000);



</script>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {

        return View(db.UserNames.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList());


    }
```

Comment: the blink is obvious because you are replacing a new HTML section. which removes the existing HTML and adds the new one. But if you feel its still irritating for you then one thing you can do is keep the HTML, that is keep the table structure and only update the data in it which will look awesome without any flickering , But it needs more work.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I do not use .html(data)?

Comment: Yes, instead you can pass JSON from the server and do a loop and just update the data inside your td's