# Ajax refresh on success - how to remove the blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen this but it does not solve my problem [ajax refresh - how to remove the blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359036/ajax-refresh-how-to-remove-the-blinking)

How can I take off the blinker from the page every 3 seconds that the Ajax refreshes without reloading the page?

The code is doing exactly what's expected, but I only haven't found a way to get around the blinker.

```
<div id="appCapsule">

</div>
```

```
let app_capsule = document.getElementById("appCapsule")

$("#appCapsule").empty();

load_messages = function(){

  $.ajax({
    url:"json/chat-content.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{recipient_id:3},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success:function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    app_capsule.innerHTML="<div id=\"\">"+ resp +"</div>";
    
    setTimeout(load_messages, 3000);
    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });   
  
}
  
load_messages();
```

Comment: Why an empty ID? That's the same as no ID at all.

Comment: What do you mean by blinker?

Comment: Instead of changing the `innerHTML`, *append* new nodes and elements whenever there is new data. You might also want to look into [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) instead of polling every 3 seconds.

Comment: @Barmar The page blinks every 3 seconds the page checks back on the server for updated data.

Comment: @Barmar Empty id, because I filled it with data only after the Ajax success.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Can you please show me a sample, I'm new to web socket.

Comment: @devsam247 here's an article that shows a PHP implementation of WebSockets https://dev.to/robertobutti/websocket-with-php-4k2c

Comment: @devsam247 You still don't need to write `id=""` when you create the element. You can always add an ID later.

Comment: @Barmar How do you mean please?

Comment: @Barmar How would that solve the blink?

Comment: I never suggested anything to solve the blink. My comments about the empty ID are unrelated to the problem, just general code style.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(load_messages, 3000);
```

Every time your ajax call is successful, your code runs it again after 3 seconds...

Safe bet that when `#appCapsule` is updated, it probably looks like the screen is blinking. Maybe instead of a timer, trigger the reload off of some user event? Or look into websockets? If you have to use the inefficient polling method, maybe use a conditional check before you mutate the DOM?

Also you have a redundancy between jQuery and javascript, maybe pick just one?

```
document.getElementById("appCapsule") === $("#appCapsule")[0]
```

I'm bias toward jQuery, as it's more readable and chainable.

```
let $app_capsule = $('#appCapsule');

load_messages = function(last_resp = null){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'json/chat-content.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      recipient_id: 3
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(resp) {
      /*
      if you're going to somehow dynamically add an id later,
      there is no point in even putting a blank one here now.

      also there is no point in .empty()ing the element if you are
      just going to repopulate it immediately. this is likely the cause of the blinking.

      consider a different method to communicate to the user that something is loading.
      */
      if (resp !== last_resp) { //only update if something changed
        $app_capsule.html(`<div>${resp}</div>`); 
      }

      setTimeout(load_messages(resp), 3000);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error loading messages: ', data);
    }
  });
}
  
load_messages();
```